# Can a single sidekiq job be picked by two threads at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I am been using sidekiq for a longtime but still always get confused with above question.

I want to confirm can there be a race condition where a single sidekiq Job is picked up by two thread simultaneously?

[Here](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#2-make-your-job-idempotent-and-transactional) it is mentioned that sidekiq doesn't guarantee if job is run only once

> Just remember that Sidekiq will execute your job at least once, not exactly once. Even a job which has completed can be re-run. Redis can go down between the point where your job finished but before Sidekiq has acknowledged it in Redis. Sidekiq makes no exactly-once guarantee at all

Any help from anyone who has faced this issue or have any expertise will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324319/can-2-sidekiq-worker-threads-process-the-same-job?rq=2

Answer (score 0):

> can there be a race condition where a single sidekiq Job is picked up by two thread simultaneously?

No.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation @mike.